# Application goes down with "New missing/unsatisfied dependencies problems"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss, jboss7.x

I need help with following issue. My application works fine for some time and then goes down with the message **New missing/unsatisfied dependencies problems**. 
The log file below. Thanks

```
18:45:20,852 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ApplicationRealm.properties_authentication (missing) dependents: [service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ApplicationRealm]

18:45:20,859 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/accredability]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
18:45:20,905 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011942: Stopping OSGi Framework
```

Comment: There should be more deatils in log above this error. This is last error JBoss reports. plz check and attach statcktrace.

Comment: I have a similar problem with a fresh install of JBoss AS 7.1.1. In my case I get the error referenced above when I stop the server. There is no additional error detail in either boot.log or server.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error. Actually, my `EC2` instance was going to retire, as well as there were low space on disk. My instance has been retired by `Amazon` and I had to launch new server and install my application again. So after lots of shifts and ups now my application is running.